# iPad 3 shouldRasterize = YES makes UILabel text cut off

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel, calayer

I have a problem when setting `shouldRasterize` to `YES` on layer.  On iPad3, the label.text has the text cut off from the bottom for about 1/5 of the size. Anyone know what's the problem is?.

```
    cellview.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0;
    cellview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    cellview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    cellview.layer.frame = rect;
    cellview.layer.shouldRasterize =YES;
    cellview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

On iPad 2, it works fine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set the rasterization's scale, because of iPad3's retina display:

```
[cellview.layer setRasterizationScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift version:

```
cellview.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 4 version

```
cellView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```